# Stop the Pathview movement at the last element

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

How can I stop the movement of the Pathview element in QML when it reaches the last element in the model(like the list view and grid view default behaviour).ie,I don't want a cyclic movement.

in the below code if we swipe right after the first("first") item last("last") will be shown (then  "Jane Doe") .what can be done to stop the further swipe in right when first is reached and further swipe in left when the last item is reached.it should stop when first or last is reached

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id:contactModel
         ListElement {
             name: "first"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Jane Doe"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "John Smith"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }

         ListElement {
             name: "Bill Jones"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Jane Doe"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "John Smith"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Bill Jones"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Jane Doe"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "last"
             icon: "pic.png"
         }
     }

         Component {
             id: delegate
             Column {
                 id: wrapper
                 Image {
                     anchors.horizontalCenter: nameText.horizontalCenter
                     width: 64; height: 64
                     source: icon
                 }
                 Text {
                     id: nameText
                     text: name
                     font.pointSize: 5
                     color: wrapper.PathView.isCurrentItem ? "red" : "black"
                 }
             }
         }

         PathView {
             anchors.fill: parent
             model: contactModel
             delegate: delegate
             snapMode:PathView.SnapOneItem
             path: Path {
                 startX: 0; startY: 100


                 PathLine { x: 640; y: 400;  }
             }
         }

}
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far. The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Here it's how implementation might look (I was not able to find available properties to do that)

```
PathView {
    property int previousCurrentIndex: 0
    currentIndex: 0
    ...

    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        var lastIndex = contactModel.count - 1
        if (currentIndex == 0 && previousCurrentIndex == lastIndex) {
            pathViewId.positionViewAtIndex(lastIndex, PathView.Beginning)
        } else if (currentIndex == lastIndex && previousCurrentIndex == 0) {
            pathViewId.positionViewAtIndex(0, PathView.Beginning)
        }
        previousCurrentIndex = currentIndex
    }
}
```

Custom property `previousCurrentIndex` is introduced and calculation of actual `currentIndex` is done on emitting of `onCurrentIndexChanged` signal

Comment: Sorry this was not the expectation. I have edited the question.i want to stop the further movement of the path view

Comment: Please check edited answer, it limits moving of PathView on item with last index in data model. You should be able to adjust this solution to what you need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in your PathView. It'll stop the view moving from the end to the start and the other way around.

```
property real previousOffsetVal: 0.

onOffsetChanged: {
            /* 10 is a threshhold, should be smaller than the total elements count*/
            if (Math.abs( previousOffsetVal - offset) > 10 ) {
                offset = previousOffsetVal
            }

            previousOffsetVal = offset
}
```